# Compare items in an existing list based on property in HQL

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, hql

Let say I have two class:

> public class A{
>
> ```
>  public virtual int Id;
>  ...
>  ...
> ```
>
> }
>
> public class B{
>
> ```
>    public virtual int Id;
>
>    public virtual A a;
>  ...
> ```
>
> }

I have a list of A. List existingObjectAList;

and also I want to search object B's which contains existingObjectAList.

How can I do this In C# with HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bs = session.CreateQuery("from B where A in (:list)"
                .SetParameterList("list", existingObjectAList)
                .List<B>();
```

Comment: is there any way to write this query without sql?